# Securing Short-term-history (STH, aka. comet) with FIWARE-PEP-STEELSKIN

Tags: fiware, fiware-sth-comet

I'm struggling around FIWARE Short Time Historic (STH, aka. Comet) securization by using Steelskin, the additional GEi of PEP Proxy GE (https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-pep-steelskin).

We finally came up with a configuration that perfectly works with orion and perseo but it does not propertly handle STH calls. It returns:

```
{ 
"name": "ACCESS_DENIED",
"message": "The user does not have the appropriate permissions to access the selected action"
}
```

But it perfectly handle orion calls with given token. Has anyone a working configuration on docker-compose schema?

Our PEP frontend looks like:

```
pep-sth-fe:
   #image: telefonicaiot/fiware-pep-steelskin:latest
   build: ./fiware-pep-steelskin
   links:
     - sth
     - keystone
     - keypass
   ports:
     - "8666:8666"
     - "11213:11211"
   environment:
     - COMPONENT_PLUGIN=rest
     - TARGET_HOST=sth
     - TARGET_PORT=8666
     - PROXY_USERNAME=pep
     - PROXY_PASSWORD=XXXXXXXX
     - ACCESS_HOST=keypass
     - ACCESS_PORT=7070
     - AUTHENTICATION_HOST=keystone
     - AUTHENTICATION_PORT=5001
```

According to: https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-pep-steelskin/blob/master/errorcodes.md

It might be a keypass configuration issue. Creating and assigning an authorised role to allow queries on pep proxied sth?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Bests!